# How to draw straight line cross center of data in scatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I wanted to draw a scatter plot with ggplot which `geom_smooth()` cross center of my data with 45 degree angle not drawing automatically.

As it shows here the geom_smooth() has small slop and I changed different method lm, auto and etc, but there was no difference.

```
geom_smooth(color = "black", alpha = 0.5, method = "lm", se = F)
```

How can I draw line in way exactly cross middle of the pink dots?

[image]

Comment: do you want the line across the middle of the pink dots only? right now it looks like geom_smooth is looking at all of the data (blue and pink) maybe try trimming the data argument you are passing in to geom smooth to only have the pink group

Comment: yes, it's across all data, I just changed color function based on value up and down, but it don't want to trim data because I need 2 other groups.

Comment: right, you don't have to lose any data, just adjust what data your are passing to geom_smooth. something like this: `geom_smooth(data = filter(df, value == "up"), ...)` if you add a dput(your_data) it would be easier to help

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)
```

This wll draw a line with a 45º angle that goes through 0.

I think `geom_smooth` is computing the regression fr all the points. Try to remove all `color` argument to get the smooth by group. You can check the different plots

```
a <- data.frame(x = c(1:10,2:11),y = c(2:11,1:10), label = c(rep("a",10),rep("b",10)))

ggplot(a, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(color = label)) + geom_smooth(aes(color = label))
ggplot(a, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(aes(color = label)) + geom_smooth(color="black")
```

Comment: thanks it works, `geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)` works fine, but it goes from corner to another, is there any way to have this line which starts and end like `geom_smooth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
geom_smooth(aes(group = type))
```

This will give a different curve for each type. You can then figure out how to exclude the others if you want

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 300
x <- seq(0,100,,n)
type <- factor(c(0,1)[sample(1:2, n, replace = TRUE)])
y <- 4 + 2*x + rnorm(n, sd=10) - 10*as.numeric(type)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, type=type)
plot(y~x, df, bg=c("blue", "pink")[df$type], pch=21)

bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col=type))
bp +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(color = "black", alpha = 0.5, method = "lm", se = F) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(group = type), data = subset(df, type==0), se=F)
```

[image]